# ASIWebPageRequest : response always in NSISOLatin1StringEncoding

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest

Trying to cache a page with images for offline mode using ASIWebPageRequest class. It works fine until I add some local strings (Czech language). ASIHTTPRequest always return response in NSISOLatin1StringEncoding so some characters are broken.

```
-(void)loadPage
{
    ASIWebPageRequest *request = [ASIWebPageRequest requestWithURL:url_server];
    [request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"book" forKey:@"request"]];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setUrlReplacementMode:ASIReplaceExternalResourcesWithLocalURLs];
}

-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSData *data = [request responseData];

    if (data)
    {
        NSFileManager *file_manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        [file_manager createFileAtPath:str_file_path contents:data attributes:nil];
    }
}
```

And the question is: how to download a page using UTF8 encoding (I know for sure the page is in UTF8).

Answer (score 0):

You can set default response encoding format.

```
[self setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```